# IP and PORT to subdomain

Tags: dns, cloudflare, roundcube, vds

I had a VDS server, Im using FastPanel.

My mail server is roundcube. And Im using CloudFlare

So, question is;

My roundcube login is https://IPaddress:8888/webmail

I want to change to for my all domain, from my cloudflare dns setting like a https://webmail.domain.com

Is that possible

I didnt try anything about this.

Comment: Well, why didn't you try anything yet? It's been 18 hours since you asked, and nobody answered. In 18 hours you could have tried a lot, and if stuff still didn't work as you expected, you could include what you've tried and how it failed in the question, so that people don't suggest something you've already ruled out. Questions that don't show any effort on the asker's side tend to get downvoted and closed. Please see [ask].